# JS Modal not displaying variables in input fields - server config requirements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

after spending a fair amount of time researching and debugging the issues, I am finally at my wits' end and would appreciate some help:

**Problem**:
Modal does not display variables insert into its INPUT fields.

**Background info:**
I am pulling records from a MySQL table which is displayed line by line, with an "EDIT" button placed in the last column of each row. The EDIT button is supposed to launch a modal populated with the records data in each INPUT field, allowing the user to edit the record.

**What I've tried so far:**

- checked whether the generated variables are empty by looking at what's printed in the source. All variables are generated correctly and have indeed values printed.
- I copied the #MyModal JS and `<div>` from the official documentation but cannot get it work either ([Link](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/))
- copied the #EDIT modal from another thread on the web which worked for another user
- included references from Google and MaxCDN instead of my own local copies of JS Bootstrap / jQuery / CSS
- tried to run the code on my XAMPP server without success, showing the some symptoms
- opened the website in IE / Chrome / Firefox / Safari (MAC), all with the same result
- ran a JS Fiddle successfully handing over the variables which makes me think that there might be a server issue / configuration requirement that I am not aware of ([LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/h64cu2vz/))

**The code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- include jQuery 3.1.0 + jQuery CSS + min JavaScript -->

    <!-- latest jQuery 3.1.0 -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!-- JavaScript for Modal, #MyModal is straight from the documentation, #edit is a solution I got off the web -->
    <script>
    $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var dataID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataID"]').val(dataID);
        var dataDate = $(e.relatedTarget).data('date');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataDate"]').val(dataDate);
    });

    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var dataID = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataID"]').val(dataID);
        var dataDate = $(e.relatedTarget).data('date');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataDate"]').val(dataDate);
        var dataTime = $(e.relatedTarget).data('time');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataTime"]').val(dataTime);
        var dataStaff = $(e.relatedTarget).data('staff');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataStaff"]').val(dataStaff);
        var dataDept = $(e.relatedTarget).data('dept');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataDept"]').val(dataDept);
        var dataProb = $(e.relatedTarget).data('prob');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataProb"]').val(dataProb);
        var dataGuest = $(e.relatedTarget).data('guest');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataGuest"]').val(dataGuest);
        var dataRoom = $(e.relatedTarget).data('room');
        $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="dataRoom"]').val(dataRoom);
    });
    </script>
    <!-- End of Modal Javascript -->
</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Button for Modal #MYMODAL"</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-keyboard="true" 
                data-id="1234"
                data-date="2001-01-31" 
                data-time="13:00" 
                data-staff="Some Name" 
                data-dept="Some Department" 
                data-prob="Problem" 
                data-guest="Guest Name" 
                data-room="1111" >Modal 1</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Button for Modal #EDIT"</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" data-keyboard="true" 
                data-id="1234"
                data-date="2001-01-31">Modal 2</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Modal MYMODAL -->
    <div class="modal modal-primary modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Record</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>ID No.: </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" id="dataID" name="dataID" value="" disabled />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date: </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="date" id="dataDate" name="dataDate" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Time: </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="time" id="dataTime" name="dataTime" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Staff: </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="dataStaff" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Department: </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="dataDept" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Problem: </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="dataProb" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Guest: </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="dataGuest" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Room No.: </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" name="dataRoom" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.Modal MYMODAL -->

    <!-- Modal EDIT-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Details</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td>ID No.: </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="text" id="dataID" name="dataID" value="" disabled />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date: </td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="date" id="dataDate" name="dataDate" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.Modal EDIT -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script needs to be at the bottom, after the html. I believe that when your script is executing, the html does not yet exist.

Comment: Turns out that when moving the script from the header to right after the modal, the input fields got populated. I knew it had to be something small ;) Thanks a lot